# EF Core new validation attribute `DeniedValues` with `StringComparison` does not works

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-8.0

EF Core new validation attribute `DeniedValues` with `StringComparison`  does not works:

```
[DeniedValues("bad", "lol", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)]
public string Name { get; set; } = "";
```

is there any solution?

Comment: It is not EF Core's attribute as far as I can see. Do you have a minimal repro?

Comment: @GuruStron
look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCnwvq0TwVY

Comment: and this is doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.deniedvaluesattribute

Comment: EF Core do not have embedded validation mechanism. You have to execute validation by yourself. In video ASP.NET provides validation during API Call.

Comment: @GuruStron
i don't understand your answer. it's actually validates "bad" or "lol" but does not validates "Bad" or "Lol"

Comment: @DevMis this one I know of already and it is not EF Core specific (see the namespace - `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`).

Comment: My bad, but EF Core still do not have any validation mechanism, It is from different area.

Comment: @DevMis _"it's actually validates "bad" or "lol" but does not validates "Bad" or "Lol""_ - this is expected, see my answer. "Bad" and "Lol" are not equal to any values from `"bad", "lol", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation isn't performed by EF Core but the classes in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. The [DeniedValuesAttribute](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/813ff97290dac82ce9c55b7c7a78c0d1cf2ff5e4/src/libraries/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/src/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/DeniedValuesAttribute.cs#L12) uses `Equals` to perform a type's default equality check. It doesn't allow variations either through flags or comparers :

```
    public override bool IsValid(object? value)
    {
        foreach (object? denied in Values)
        {
            if (denied is null ? value is null : denied.Equals(value))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

You'll have to create your own custom validation attribute to use case insensitive comparison, perhaps something like this :

```
[CLSCompliant(false)]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DeniedStringValuesAttribute(StringComparison comparisonType,params string?[] values) 
    : DeniedValuesAttribute (values)
{
    public StringComparison ComparisonType { get; }=comparisonType;

    public override bool IsValid(object? value)
    {
        foreach (string? denied in Values)
        {
            if (String.Equals(denied,value as string,ComparisonType))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`DeniedValuesAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.deniedvaluesattribute.-ctor?view=net-8.0) ctor accepts array of objects to deny:

```
public DeniedValuesAttribute (params object?[] values);
```

Adding `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` will just add corresponding enum value to this collection (i.e. if you set somehow value of property to [`StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=net-8.0) enum value it will be denied also) and will have no effect on comparison used.

If you want to perform case-insensitive validation here I would recommend to look into something like [`FluentValidation`](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/) or maybe implementing [custom validation attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#custom-attributes) (which should not be hard).

P.S.

This attribute comes from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and it is not EF Core specific.